# pthread scheduling issue while using sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, sleep, scheduling

I spawn four detachable threads and in each thread i am giving 1 second sleep (sleep is my application requirement) because of that OS only schedule the 2 threads and other two threads are sitting ideal but if i remove sleep all threads are scheduled by OS but my application requirement is each thread should go to sleep mode once it complete its task

I already tried sleep, nanosleep and set the threads properties, priority and round robin scheduling in pthread but not success.

Please suggest what else I can do to solve my application issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  If you just want the threads to wait suspended until there's work for them to do, look into condition variables..

Comment: Do you put your threads to sleep while they are holding a mutex locked, or some similar thing?  Sleeping does not unlock mutexes, manipulate semaphores, signal condition variables, etc.

Comment: A [mcve] would be in order here.

Comment: @Dmitri, My all the threads need to send some status continuously, but once one thread send the status it should wait for one second.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I am not using any mutex, semaphore in my threads because I am not updating any global data just sending some status

Comment: Why do they need to send status continuously if they're not doing anything else?  Why not just once before they wait?

Comment: @Dmitri, Application design requirement.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Difficult to put the code here because its real time application code. I will try to reproduce the scenario with sample code if possible

Answer (score 0):

Now I am giving one second interval for each thread using below logic and removed the sleep from my code and issue is resolved (now all four threads are scheduled).

```
(void) gettimeofday (&nowtime, NULL);
unsigned long long currentTime = (nowtime.tv_sec * 1000000) + nowtime.tv_usec;
unsigned long long FutureTime =  ((nowtime.tv_sec + interval) * 1000000) + nowtime.tv_usec;
while(FutureTime >= currentTime)
{
    (void) gettimeofday (&nowtime, NULL);
    currentTime = (nowtime.tv_sec * 1000000) + nowtime.tv_usec;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure a busy loop like this is a good idea?  Your thread won't sleep... it'll just eat up as many CPU cycles as it can even though it's supposed to be just waiting.  Is the only reason you're not using the other methods you tried that the thread doesn't seem to be scheduled *during the wait*?  That might not be a bad thing, as long as it's scheduled when the wait ends.

Comment: Yes, It will use cpu cycle but at least its schedule to all the threads not sitting ideal, if any better idea is available, Please suggest because I am also thinking for cpu cycle.

Comment: Why do sleeping threads need to be scheduled while they sleep?  Isn't it enough that they're schedule *after* the wait, when they might actually need to do something?  If you want to be able to interrupt the wait, you could try a timed wait on a condition variable, a timed wait on a file descriptor, or possibly use signals.  Or at least, you could yield the time slice each time you check the interval and determine the wait isn't finished.